# Qualitative study of the solution to a Cauchy problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let us consider the differential equation
\begin{equation}
y''=\frac{y'}{2\sqrt{y}}\;\; (y>0)
\end{equation}
1). Prove that every non-constant solution is strictly monotone;

2). Consider the Cauchy problem
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
y''=\frac{y'}{2\sqrt{y}}\\
y(0)=u\\
y'(0)=v
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
Determine the set of points $(u,v)\in \mathbb{R}^+\times\mathbb{R}$ s.t. the maximal solution to the problem is non constant and defined on the whole real line $\mathbb{R}$. For these points $(u,v)$, determine the limits of the solution for $t\rightarrow \pm \infty$.

For the first point I supposed $y'(t_0)=0$ so that $y''(t_0)=0$ whence the constant solution $y\equiv y(t_0).$ Could it work?

For the second point, I have integrated the differential equation by using the initial conditions but I don't know how to proceed...

Comment: Have you found $y'$ in terms of $y$?

Comment: I have obtained $y'(t)=\sqrt{y(t)}+v-\sqrt{u}$ but then?